# Alterar cores icones dinamicamente

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho a seguinte dúvida: 
Tenho vários icones no meu projeto, alguns brancos e outros preto.

Existe a possibilidade de alterar a cor do icone sem precisar importar um icone ja na cor especifica? Ex: Deixa-lo Vermelho, Amarelo, etc...

**Exemplo onde funciona, mas não é onde preciso:**

O BottomNavigation faz isso, onde os icones são originalmente preto e a cor definida é ColorPrimaryDark.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ideia seria fazer isso mas nos icones da ActionBar.
Eu gostaria de saber como poderia fazer isso e se é possível?

Exemplos & sugestões que encontrei: (Não consegui fazer funcionar)

## 1

```
Drawable mDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourdrawable); 
mDrawable.setColorFilter(new 
PorterDuffColorFilter(0xffff00,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
```

## 2

```
ImageView lineColorCode = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.line_color_code);
int color = Color.parseColor("#AE6118"); //The color u want             
lineColorCode.setColorFilter(color);
```

Comment: Você está usando BottomNavigationView?  Seria interessante você colocar na sua pergunta, porque talvez tenha formas mias viáveis para resolver o problema,.

Comment: O BottomNavigationView citei como exemplo apenas. O que eu quero acertar é na ActionBar, mas de qualquer forma editei a pergunta. @acklay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este caso, se preferir, pode usar apenas o XML. Bastaria criar um `<selector>` com o nome por exemplo, `item_selector.xml`, usando o `state_check` como `true` e inserir no seu diretório `drawable`, ficando desta forma:  `res/drawable/item_selector.xml`. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"  />
</selector>
```

Para usar, você precisa definir o `itemIconTint` e o `itemTextColor` para que o texto também fique da mesma cor quando estiver selecionado. Veja:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/item_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/item_selector"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_bar_menu" />
```

Comment: Eu não quero um BottomNavigationView, eu só citei como exemplo,. Eu gostaria de colorir um icone/image simples

Comment: @TiagoIB mesmo assim, você pode usar da mesma forma.